# Importing Files Into Excel - Skip if not Found

Tags: vba, excel, onerror

This is my first question here, I have a macro to import .txt files "Semicolon" delimited into  Excel. Each file is name specific, and each file is imported in a new sheet. But if one of theses files doesn't exists, the macro Fails. I want to add an "On Erro" to handle these cases, if the file doesn't exists, skip it. Heres the code:

```
Sub Importar_Dep()

Dim Caminho As String


Caminho = Sheets("DADOS").Cells(5, 8).Value
    Sheets("DEP").Select
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & Caminho, _
        Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "RECONQUISTA_DEP_0"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 850
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code with the check if the file exist:

```
Sub Importar_Dep()

    Dim Caminho As String
    Caminho = Sheets("DADOS").Cells(5, 8).Value
    Sheets("DEP").Select

    '+++++ Added block to check if file exists +++++
    Dim FS
    Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim TextFile_FullPath As String
    'The textfile_fullPath should be like:
    TextFile_FullPath = "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\" & _
                         RECONQUISTA_DEP_0 & _
                         ".txt"

    If FS.FileExists(TextFile_FullPath) Then
    '++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
            "TEXT;" & Caminho, _
            Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
            .Name = "RECONQUISTA_DEP_0"
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFilePlatform = 850
            .TextFileStartRow = 1
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
            .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
            .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With

    End If

End Sub
```

Like in your comment, if you want to run through all files that have a certain name in common (a filter), you can use this code.  The above modifications have then became useless because with this you don't have to check if file exists anymore since it will just go through all existing files.  You could have to check if the folder exists though:

```
Sub RunThroughAllFiles()

    Dim Caminho As String
    Caminho = Sheets("DADOS").Cells(5, 8).Value
    Sheets("DEP").Select

    Dim FS
    Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim Filter As String: Filter = "RECONQUISTA_DEP_*.txt"
    Dim dirTmp As String

    If FS.FolderExists(Caminho) Then
        dirTmp = Dir(Caminho & "\" & Filter)
        Do While Len(dirTmp) > 0
            Call Importar_Dep(Caminho & "\" & dirTmp, _
                            Left(dirTmp, InStrRev(dirTmp, ".") - 1))
            dirTmp = Dir
        Loop
    Else
        MsgBox "Folder """ & Caminho & """ does not exists", vbExclamation
    End If

End Sub

Sub Importar_Dep(iFullFilePath As String, iFileNameWithoutExtension)

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & iFullFilePath, _
        Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = iFileNameWithoutExtension
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 850
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

End Sub
```

For more information see **[Dir](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262726%28v=vs.60%29.aspx), [FileExists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265024%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) and [FolderExists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265025%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)**

Comment: Thank you very much, bro! It works like a charm! I have another question, if you could help me.. how can I set the "RECONQUISTA_DEP_0" as a variable? Like, make it import the file even if the name is "RECONQUISTA_DEP_12", something like "RECONQUISTA_DEP_*"

Comment: @user3271315, Glad I could help :)  Sure, i'll edit my answer.

Comment: Now it didn't work, I don't know why.. it just doesn't import anything, even if there is a file in the folder... For instance, my "Caminho" value is "C:\Bases Geradas\Movel Reconquista\2014\16 01 14
"

Comment: @DiegoPatrocinio, how will the "Caminho" value change?  it is holding the full file path right? i.e.: C:\blah\textfile.txt

Comment: No, it holds only the directory. Let me explain. Everyday I receive these files through e-mail and paste them into a new folder with the current date. The file name is always "RECONQUISTA_DEP_*" where "* = any Number, and there is only on file per day. Then I paste the path for the folder I created in a cell, so "Caminho" reads this cell. So what I want is to make something like Open: ( Caminho & FileName & ".txt") but if I set "FileName = RECONQUISTA_DEP_*" the Macro fails..

Comment: @DiegoPatrocinio, here you go.  This will loop through all the files contained within the `Caminho` folder that have "RECONQUISTA_DEP_*" as common name.  If you don't want it to loop, just remove the `Do While Len(dirTmp) > 0`, `dirTmp = Dir` and the following `Loop`.

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry, I had just left office yesterday when you answered.. so, just tried it, didn't work =( I just doesnt import anything.. no error message, nothing..

Comment: @DiegoPatrocinio, add the last three lines above the first `End Sub`.  To add a warning when the folder does not exist.  And tell me what happened.

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry, it worked just fine! It was my mistake! The correct path for "Caminho" is Cells(5,5) and I was running the macro with (5,8) thats why it wasnt working! Thank you very much, man, you helped me A LOT OF! If there is anything I can do, just hit me up!

Comment: @DiegoPatrocinio; No problem, I'm really glad it worked out finally.  Anyhow, the added `MsgBox` is a must so you can see what happens when it does not do anything, I should have put it before :)  See you around!

Comment: Hey buddy, sorry to bug you again, but can you help me with a last question? When I use the code you sent me, if there are more than a file in the folder, it imports then "side by side" I need it to import them "under" the last one.. like, if the first file goes up to the colunm D, the next will be imported on E... I'll add the code  under this comment.

Comment: @DiegoPatrocinio; you should start a new question for that so it is easier for other users to find the topic they're looking for. Thx

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21608393/import-multiple-text-files-in-the-same-excel-sheet

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
Sub Abrir_PORT()

    Dim Caminho As String
    Caminho = Sheets("DADOS").Cells(5, 5).Value
    Sheets("PORT").Select

    Dim FS
    Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim Filter As String: Filter = "ATENTO_TLMKT_REC*.txt"
    Dim dirTmp As String

    If FS.FolderExists(Caminho) Then
        dirTmp = Dir(Caminho & "\" & Filter)
        Do While Len(dirTmp) > 0
            Call Importar_PORT(Caminho & "\" & dirTmp, _
                            Left(dirTmp, InStrRev(dirTmp, ".") - 1))
            dirTmp = Dir
        Loop
    End If

End Sub

Sub Importar_PORT(iFullFilePath As String, iFileNameWithoutExtension)

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & iFullFilePath, _
        Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = iFileNameWithoutExtension
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 850
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

    iRow = 2

    Do While Sheets("PORT").Cells(iRow, 1) <> ""

                If Cells(iRow, 2) = IsNumber Then

                Else

                Rows(iRow).Select
                Selection.EntireRow.Delete

                iRow = iRow - 1
                contagem = contagem + 1

                End If

 iRow = iRow + 1

 Loop

    End With

End Sub
```