# Import Multiple Text Files in the same excel Sheet

Tags: vba, excel, import

I'm running a Macro on Excel to import multiple .txt files and with a filter set to the filename, so it acts like a wildcard. Every file has the same layout, it's Semicolon delimited, has a header and 11 colunms.

The macro works fine, except its importing the files "Side by Side" or "horizontally". Instead of import the next file "under" (like, the first file goes up to the row 10, then next one start importing at row 11), it start importing in the next colunm (the first goes up the colunm "K", the next one start importing on colunm L).

How can I fix it? Heres the code:

```
Sub Abrir_PORT()

    Dim Caminho As String
    Caminho = Sheets("DADOS").Cells(5, 5).Value
    Sheets("PORT").Select

    Dim FS
    Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim Filter As String: Filter = "ATENTO_TLMKT_REC*.txt"
    Dim dirTmp As String

    If FS.FolderExists(Caminho) Then
        dirTmp = Dir(Caminho & "\" & Filter)
        Do While Len(dirTmp) > 0
            Call Importar_PORT(Caminho & "\" & dirTmp, _
                            Left(dirTmp, InStrRev(dirTmp, ".") - 1))
            dirTmp = Dir
        Loop
    End If

End Sub

Sub Importar_PORT(iFullFilePath As String, iFileNameWithoutExtension)

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & iFullFilePath, _
        Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = iFileNameWithoutExtension
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 850
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

    iRow = 2

    Do While Sheets("PORT").Cells(iRow, 1) <> ""

                If Cells(iRow, 2) = IsNumber Then

                Else

                Rows(iRow).Select
                Selection.EntireRow.Delete

                iRow = iRow - 1
                contagem = contagem + 1

                End If

 iRow = iRow + 1

 Loop

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a check if `Range("A1")` is empty so it starts at `A1` if `A1` is empty...

**Tested and working:**

```
Sub Importar_PORT(iFullFilePath As String, iFileNameWithoutExtension)

    Dim lngStartRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        If .Range("A1") = "" Then
            lngStartRow = 1
        Else
            lngStartRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1
        End If
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & iFullFilePath, _
        Destination:=Range("$A$" & lngStartRow))
```

Comment: Just perfect! Wroking like a charm! Thank you very much again, man! And thank you too, @BernardSaucier!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested but it seems like **replacing** :

```
Sub Importar_PORT(iFullFilePath As String, iFileNameWithoutExtension)

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & iFullFilePath, _
        Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
```

**with** :

```
Sub Importar_PORT(iFullFilePath As String, iFileNameWithoutExtension)

    afterLast = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & iFullFilePath, _
        Destination:=Range("$A$" & afterLast))
```

**would** work fine.

Comment: It did work but not porpely, it does import the next file under the next one, but its removing more rows than it should. If you look, I have a "Do While" running so it'll keep only one header, so it checks the first colunm, excluding the first cell, if its not numeric, its the header, so its deleted. With your code its deleting tons of rows.. any clue?

Comment: Maybe because `Sub Importar_PORT` is ran from a module and that you should have put a reference to the worksheet: `afterLast = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1`.  Else I don't know why...