# Auto Launch Macro After Text File Load on Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet "CMReport" that loads from an external text file when the workbook opens.
I want to be able to launch a macro on the file when the workbook opens, but can't get it to happen. I am not sure what I am doing wrong... sure it is something simple (I hope)

I have this in the VBA ThisWorkbook

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Run "CMReportCleanUp"
End Sub
```

This code in a Module named OnOpen

```
Sub CMReportCleanUp()
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet, Sheet2 As Worksheet, Sheet3 As Worksheet, Sheet4 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, LRow As Long, R As Long
    Dim CM As String, School As String
    Dim delRng As Range
    Dim LastRow As Integer, LastRow2 As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set Sheet = Excel.Worksheets("CMReport")
    Set Sheet2 = Excel.Worksheets("IEPReport")
    Set Sheet3 = Excel.Worksheets("CaseManager")

    'Add CaseManager and School to each row
    With Sheet
        LRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row  'Get last row of Column A.

        'Cells contain "Case Manager"
        For i = 1 To LRow  'Loop through cells in Column A.
            If InStr(1, .Cells(i, 1).Value, "Case Manager", vbTextCompare) Then  'Check to see if the cell contains "Case Manager".
                CM = .Cells(i, 1).Value  'Store the Case Manager's name in a variable.

                'Store the row numbers which have "Case Manager", it will be deleted later.
                If delRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set delRng = .Rows(i)
                Else
                    Set delRng = Union(delRng, .Rows(i))
                End If
            Else
                .Cells(i, 6).Value = CM  'Store the Case Manager in Column F.
            End If

            If InStr(1, .Cells(i, 1).Value, "Elementary", vbTextCompare) Then  'Check to see if the cell contains "Elementary".
                School = .Cells(i, 1).Value  'Store the School in a variable.

                'Store the row numbers which have "Elementary", it will be deleted later.
                If delRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set delRng = .Rows(i)
                Else
                    Set delRng = Union(delRng, .Rows(i))
                End If
            Else
                .Cells(i, 7).Value = School  'Store the School in Column G.
            End If

            If InStr(1, .Cells(i, 1).Value, "Middle", vbTextCompare) Then  'Check to see if the cell contains "Middle".
                School = .Cells(i, 1).Value  'Store the School in a variable.

                'Store the row numbers which have "Middle", it will be deleted later.
                If delRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set delRng = .Rows(i)
                Else
                    Set delRng = Union(delRng, .Rows(i))
                End If
            Else
                .Cells(i, 7).Value = School  'Store the School in Column G.
            End If

            If InStr(1, .Cells(i, 1).Value, "High", vbTextCompare) Then  'Check to see if the cell contains "High".
                School = .Cells(i, 1).Value  'Store the School in a variable.

                'Store the row numbers which have "High", it will be deleted later.
                If delRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set delRng = .Rows(i)
                Else
                    Set delRng = Union(delRng, .Rows(i))
                End If
            Else
                .Cells(i, 7).Value = School  'Store the School in Column G.
            End If

            If InStr(1, .Cells(i, 1).Value, "Academy", vbTextCompare) Then  'Check to see if the cell contains "Academy".
                School = .Cells(i, 1).Value  'Store the School in a variable.

                'Store the row numbers which have "Academy", it will be deleted later.
                If delRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set delRng = .Rows(i)
                Else
                    Set delRng = Union(delRng, .Rows(i))
                End If
            Else
                .Cells(i, 7).Value = School  'Store the School in Column G.
            End If

            If InStr(1, .Cells(i, 1).Value, "Preschool", vbTextCompare) Then  'Check to see if the cell contains "Preschool".
                School = .Cells(i, 1).Value  'Store the School in a variable.

                'Store the row numbers which have "Preschool", it will be deleted later.
                If delRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set delRng = .Rows(i)
                Else
                    Set delRng = Union(delRng, .Rows(i))
                End If
            Else
                .Cells(i, 7).Value = School  'Store the School in Column G.
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    If Not delRng Is Nothing Then delRng.Delete  'Delete the rows which contain "Case Manager"

    Sheet.Cells(1, 6).Value = "Case Manager"  'Assign Case Manager Label to Column Header
    Sheet.Cells(1, 7).Value = "School"  'Assign School Label to Column Header

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    'Delete "Case Manager:" from cells
    Cells.Replace What:="Case Manager: ", _
    Replacement:="", _
    LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    MatchCase:=False, _
    SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

EDIT #1
I setup this under ThisWorkbook

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
     Run "Test"
End Sub
```

and this under a Module

```
Sub Test()
    MsgBox Date
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = Date
End Sub
```

... and it worked just fine.

Comment: Try to replace `Run "CMReportCleanUp"` by `OnOpen.CMReportCleanUp`

Comment: The macro does not fire at all?

Comment: Right... the macro doesn't fire at all.
If I change it to OnOpen I get a compile error...

Comment: Is the `Sub CMReportCleanUp()` code located in the same workbook as for the `Private Sub Workbook_Open()`?  Also, did you try my suggestion?

Comment: Yes... the `Private Sub Workbook_Open()` is under ThisWorkbook & `Sub CMReportCleanUp` is under a Module in the same Workbook. I can run another MsgBox macro just fine the same way I have this setup, just not this macro.

Comment: Try replacing `Run "CMReportCleanUp"` with just `CMReportCleanUp` - just call the macro directly instead of using Run

Comment: @barrowc - that didn't work either. The Run command works when I setup a macro the same way that just runs a MsgBox with the current Date. So I am thinking I need to run it after my text data refreshes but I don't know how to go about doing that.

Comment: if you put a `MsgBox "test"` on the first line in `Sub CMReportCleanUp()` it does not get triggered?

Comment: Let me clarify...  see EDIT #1

Comment: Ok, but how do you know that `Sub CMReportCleanUp()` does not launch at all?  It is kind of weird that it does not launch, that is why you could try to pop a message box on the first line (or a break point) of `Sub CMReportCleanUp()` to confirm the code does not run.

Comment: Ok so it does launch... how do I get it to run after the data from the text file imports to my sheet?

Comment: So, it is not `Sub CMReportCleanUp()` that you want to be launched at `Workbook.Open` but the code that loads from txt file; then you want to continue with `Sub CMReportCleanUp()`.  Am I right?  Then you cannot run `Sub CMReportCleanUp()` in `Workbook.Open`.  You have to run the code that loads from txt file at `Workbook.Open` and at the end of the code that loads txt file, you call `Sub CMReportCleanUp()`.  That did not work?

Comment: That would work and I could do that, but my text file loads automatically when I open Excel... it is a data refresh from a file linked to my spreadsheet. How would I create the code to do that?

Comment: How much time does it take for the data to be refreshed from txt file (approx).  Then you could try `Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("hh:mm:ss"), "CMReportCleanUp"` to delay the call to the sub for a certain amount of time.

Comment: It only takes a couple seconds... is there an easy way to import a csv file from a specific location through vba into my sheet?

Comment: It is pretty straight forward.  You could record a macro to give you an idea and/or check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21608393/import-multiple-text-files-in-the-same-excel-sheet/21609131#21609131).

Answer (score 0):

try not to use obvious variable names wich could confuse excel excel like sheet2 :

```
Set Sheet = Excel.Worksheets("CMReport")
Set Sheet2 = Excel.Worksheets("IEPReport")
Set Sheet3 = Excel.Worksheets("CaseManager")
```

try with

```
Set Sh1 = thisworkbook.sheets("CMReport")
Set Sh2 = thisworkbook.sheets("IEPReport")
Set Sh3 = thisworkbook.sheets("CaseManager")
```

Also, no need to use RUN , to call a macro from the same workbook

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
CMReportCleanUp
End Sub
```

Aside from that , add a breakpoint (or a simple msgbox "hello" ) at the beginning of your sub, so you'll see if it really triggers, or just does 'nothing'