# Cycling Through Files in a Specified Folder and Importing them into Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to find a way to have Excel cycle through a variety of HTML files and import them one at a time, formatting each one in a specified way before moving onto the next file.  The files are all in FOLDER2.  How can I modify this to account for not just FILE but for FILE 1....n?  One immediate issue I'm encountering is that I'm receiving "Run-time error '1004': Microsoft Excel could not open or read this query file."  I suspect this is because it is HTML and not XML.  When I manually tell Excel to select ALL files there is no problem, but perhaps the macro isn't doing that?

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "FINDER;file:///C:/Users/FOLDER1/FOLDER2/FILE", Destination:= _
        Range("$A$1"))
        .CommandType = 0
        .Name = "FILE"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

I am trying to modify the following code so that I can simply choose the folder and have it run through that way.  Is this a reasonable approach?

```
Sub ImportXMLData()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String
Dim xlWkBk As Workbook, xmlFile As Workbook, LastRow As Long
strFolder = GetFolder
If strFolder = "" Then Exit Sub
strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.html", vbNormal)
Set xlWkBk = ThisWorkbook
While strFile <> ""
  LastRow = xlWkBk.Sheets(1).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1
  Set xmlFile = Workbooks.OpenXML(Filename:=strFolder & "\" & strFile)
  xmlFile.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy
  xlWkBk.Sheets(1).Cells(LastRow, 1).Paste
  xmlFile.Close SaveChanges:=False
  strFile = Dir()
Wend
Set xmlFile = Nothing: Set xlWkBk = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function GetFolder() As String
Dim oFolder As Object
GetFolder = ""
Set oFolder = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a folder", 0)
If (Not oFolder Is Nothing) Then GetFolder = oFolder.Items.Item.Path
Set oFolder = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Maybe **[THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21555957/2687063)** could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `FileSystemObject` (need to add reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime) to loop through the contents of a folder:

```
sub loopThroughFolder(folderPath as string)

dim fso as new FileSystemObject
dim fileObj as file

for each fileObj in fso.GetFolder(folderPath).Files
 if filenameFitsCriteria(fileObj.name) then
  importFile(fileObj.Path)
next

end sub
```

For an interface to select a folder, you can look into:

```
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
```

Comment: Thanks!  VBA doesn't seem to want me to run the code when I add (folderPath As String) though, it opens up the macros window and doesn't show me any subs by the name of your sub for some reason.  Do you happen to know why this might be?

Comment: Yes, this is a sub that you have to call from another sub where you get the folder path.  You could remove the `folderPath as string` and it will run on its own, but you'll have to add a line in the beginning where you select the folder, possibly using the `msoFileDialogFolderPicker` that I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Let me try that out.

Comment: You could also just call the `GetFolder()` function you wrote, instead of writing a new function using `msoFileDialogFolderPicker`.

Comment: I gave that a shot, but it tells me that GetFolder() is ambiguous.  Would you happen to have an idea of how to prevent this from happening?  Thank you again for all of your help.

Comment: Maybe you've defined `GetFolder()` twice in the same module?  A quick workaround would be to just change the name to `GetFolderPath()` or something like that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49175/discussion-between-sigil-and-stopwatch)